# can we add <reference> tag as child of any other <reference> tag

Tags: magento-1.7, layout, blocks

can we add  tag as child of any other  tag

```
<support_index_index>
    <reference name="content">      
          <reference name="foo"> 
              <block type="support/support" name="support" template="support/support.phtml" />
          </reference> 
    </reference>
</support_index_index>
```

Comment: What would you like to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can not, This is against the behavior of xml in magento.

Answer (score 1):

It works but it does not mean anything. Any reference references a globally unique block name. To reference the block "foo", just use:

```
<support_index_index>
    <reference name="foo"> 
        <block type="support/support" name="support" template="support/support.phtml" />
    </reference> 
</support_index_index>
```

(wherever "foo" is located)